Get cookie by subdomain wise in react js using universal-cookie
I am using universal-cookie in my React JS project to store a token. I am setting cookies for both the domain and subdomain. My domain is testdomain.com and my subdomain is demo.subdomain.com. When I set the cookie for the domain and try to access it from the subdomain, I am getting the domain cookie instead of the subdomain cookie.
Here is the my function to set the cookie
export const setCookies = (key: string, value: string) => {
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  const currentDate = moment();
  const newDate = currentDate.add(2, "days").toDate();
  cookies.set(key, value, {
    path: "/",
    expires: newDate,
    secure: true,
  });
};

In the component, I am accessing the cookie using getCookies function
export const getCookies = (key: string) => {
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  return cookies.get(key);
};

Here I want to specify the cookie by subdomain. In the cookie it is already stored for both i.e. for subdomain and domain.
I have used same key name.

Can you show the cookies your browser has stored (application tab of dev tools), and what Cookie header(s) the browser actually sends with the request (network panel)?
